# How to print a formatted SOAPMessage?

Tags: java, xml, soap, javax.xml

I have a `SOAPMessage` (found in `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage`).

However the only way to print it seems to be `soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);` However this doesn't have any new lines and with a large `SOAPMessage` it can be difficult to read.

Further, using `System.out.println(soapMessage.toString());` just prints out:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl@76c7e77a
```

I looked at [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java), [How to print SOAPMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842182/how-to-print-soapmessage)  and [How to convert SOAPBody to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149528/how-to-convert-soapbody-to-string) but neither fix the issue of newlines and/or formatting a `SOAPMessage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind adding additional dependencies to your project then jdom provides good formatted output for XML.

The documentation at [jdom.org](http://jdom.org) is well worth a look.

It's a little convoluted but you can write the XML in to a JDOM Document object and then use the XMLOutputter object to print it in a pretty format.:

```
    // write the SoapMessage to a String called xml
    File file= new File(pathToFile);
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    soapMessage.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
    SAXBuilder b = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = b.build(file);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutputter.output(doc, System.out);
```